# AppWidgetProvider, onUpdate gets called several times on start

Tags: android, widget

I have a problem regarding `AppWidgetProvider`. When the phone starts up the `onUpdate()` method for the `AppWidgetProvider` gets called four times in a row, all containing the same `appWidgetId`. I can't figure out why it's happening. Does anyone have a clue?

I got two types of `super classes`, `Main` and `MainScroll`, and `four classes(widgets)` that extends the 
`super classes`.

**Example widget**

```
public class WidgetMedium extends Main {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}
```

The manifest

```
        <receiver android:name=".activity.Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".activity.MainScroll">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".activity.WidgetMedium"
        android:label="Swedroid Widget 4x3"
        android:icon="@drawable/widget_application">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_medium" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".activity.WidgetScrollMedium"
        android:label="Swedroid Widget 4x3 Scroll"
        android:icon="@drawable/widget_application">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_scroll_provider_medium" />
    </receiver>

     <receiver android:name=".activity.WidgetLarge"
        android:label="Swedroid Widget 4x4"
        android:icon="@drawable/widget_application">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.swedroid.widget.activity.WidgetScrollLarge"
        android:label="Swedroid Widget 4x4 Scroll"
        android:icon="@drawable/widget_application">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_scroll_provider_large" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your AppWidgetProvider's onUpdate method? It might be that you are looping through the widgets and updating for each.

Comment: The onUpdate method is really simple, I'm looping through the widgets and starts a IntentService for each of them. It should not cause this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `Main` and `MainScroll` classes are only super classes I thing they shouldn't be `AppWidgetProviders` but rather `abstract` classes, therefore, the `receiver` definitions are not needed for them in the Manifest.

Also I think the `intent-filter` below is not needed for the other four `reciever` definitions.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that all four receivers in your case are active and they all receive the same intent to update your widget. Could you please add the code where you create update intent in your application?